# Quick help on Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL javascript Function

Tags: javascript, token

I have the following piece of code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv_rm").hide();
        $(".show_hide_rm").show();
        $('.show_hide_rm).click(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv_rm").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

however I don't understand why i'm having the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL index.php:222 which line 222 is

```
$('.show_hide_rm).click(function(){
```

I'll appreciate all your help, thank you very much!

Comment: You forgot a quote --> `$('.show_hide_rm).click(function(){`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The syntax error is too basic. The syntax highlight already describes the problem. Just notice the red text.

Comment: $('.show_hide_rm' <- missing quote

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing quotes `'`

```
     $('.show_hide_rm').click(function(){...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show_hide_rm).click(function(){
```

Should read

```
$('.show_hide_rm').click(function(){
```

You missed a closing quote.